# Push index into different variables by $scopes from different controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, push

I have some problem to push my input from my form

there is some code lines in the below where the error detected
I also have recreated it on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/edenlyriene/pen/JXjExQ)

```
$scope.dish.comments.push(Object.keys{rating: $scope.comment.rating, comment: $scope.comment.comment, author: $scope.comment.author, date: $scope.comment.date});
```

So, everytime I submit my form, I always get a notification like this in the console

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined

I have stated `$scope.dish = dish;`in the other controller, so I hope that I can access it from another controller, but it didn't work as I hope

Comment: you have `$scope.dish` undefined, try initializing it before using it... `$scope.dish = {}`

Comment: Controller Scope is Not Global  you may need to call json from api or from file or define insame controller

Answer (score 1):

You are trying share data between two controllers, I recommend to use service factory for your DishDetails and then inject dependencies on both controllers and then modified data, will be reflected to each controller.

Here is how you can share data using factory service.

```js
function factory() {
  var service = {
    set: setData,
    get: getData
  };

  service.records = [{
    FirstName: 'FirstName',
    LastName: 'LastName',
    Age: '21'
  }];
  return service;


  function getData() {
    return service.records;
  }

  function setData(data) {
    service.records.push(data);
  }
}

angular
  .module('mainApp', [])

.factory('dataRecords', factory)

.controller('AddDataController', function($scope, dataRecords) {
  $scope.AddRecord = function() {
    var data = {
      FirstName: $scope.FirstName,
      LastName: $scope.LastName,
      Age: $scope.Age
    }
    dataRecords.set(data)
  }
})

.controller('ViewDataController', function($scope, dataRecords) {
  $scope.records = dataRecords.get();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<div ng-app="mainApp">
  <div ng-controller="AddDataController">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="LastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name">Age:
    <input type="number" ng-model="Age">
    <button type="button" ng-click="AddRecord()">ADD</botton>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ViewDataController" class="container">

    <h3>Record List Controller</h3>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="person in records">
        <td>{{ person.FirstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.LastName }}</td>
        <td>{{ person.Age }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May you help me by giving a short logic for the service factory?

Answer (score 0):

Add your ng-controller="DishDetailController" to the parent row-content div so the other controllers will inherit $scope.dish. Therefore:

```
<div class="row row-content" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" >
      ...
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="DishCommentController">
      ...
      </div>
</div>
```